# JavaScript regular expression pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
[link](url)
```

I am trying to write a regular expression that looks for the pattern above and returns the following code:

```
<a href="url">link</a>
```

Comment: You'd start by learning the basics of regular expressions from reputable sources like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Maybe use some already existing solution like Markdown; [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) is a JavaScript Markdown converter and editor similar to this used here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

[By reading a tutorial, I guess.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

```
str = str.replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]\(([^)]*)\)/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>');
```

This looks a bit daunting, I admit. Here is an explanation:

```
/        # just the delimiter for the regex (like " for a string)
\[       # match a literal [
(        # start capturing group $1 for later access
  [^\]]  # match any character except ]
  *      # 0 or more of those (as many as possible)
)        # end of capturing group $1
\]       # match a literal ]
\(       # match a literal (
(        # start capturing group $2 for later access
  [^)]   # match any character except )
  *      # 0 or more of those (as many as possible)
)        # end of capturing group $2
\)       # match a literal )
/        # end of regex
g        # make regex global to replace ALL occurrences
```

Then we reference the two captured groups with `$1` and `$2` in the replacement string. `$1` is capturing characters inside `[]` and `$2` is capturing characters inside `()`.

Comment: I really wish people wouldn't encourage these sorts of questions.

Comment: @user1689607 I see your point, but I believe 3 downvotes and a closed question within 4 minutes is discouraging enough. And I felt that a tutorial link alone would be a bit of a dodgy answer.

Comment: Yes a tutorial link alone would be a poor answer. I'm certainly not criticizing the content of your answer... just the presence of it. ;-)

Comment: @user1689607, I didn't like the encouragement he gave but this is well hell of a fine answer +1 !